# Delete metadata in WP admin custom columns

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to delete metadata from the admin panel of my custom post in WP. I created my custom column and display the desired metadata inside but when I try to create a button to delete the metadata nothing happens.

My code tries to delete the metadata and user post with foreach.

Any help would be much appreciated.

code Done! 05/05/15:

Change Admin Columns:

```
add_action( "manage_favor_posts_columns", "change_columns" );
function change_columns( $cols ) {
  $cols = array(
    'cb'       => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'title'     => __( 'Título del favor', 'trans' ),
    'usuarios_registrados'      => __('Usuarios Registrados', 'trans'),
    'date'     => __( 'Fecha publicación', 'trans' ),
  );
  return $cols;
}

add_action( "manage_posts_custom_column", "custom_columns_phi", 10, 2 );
```

Add output metas and delete link in columns:

```
function custom_columns_phi( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case "usuarios_registrados":
            $favor_post_meta_datos = get_post_meta ($post_id, 'usuarios_favores');
            foreach($favor_post_meta_datos as $term_post){      
                $user_phi_name = get_userdata ($term_post);
                ?>
                <li><?echo $user_phi_name->first_name;?> | <a href="<?php print wp_nonce_url(admin_url('edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=favor&value_phi_user='.$term_post.'&value_phi_post='.$post_id));?>">Cancelar</a></li>
                <?
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Add init function in admin screen:

```
function phi_admin_preload_get () {
if ( isset($_GET['value_phi_user'] )) {
        $phi_get_post = $_GET['value_phi_post'];
        $phi_get_user = $_GET['value_phi_user'];
        delete_post_meta ($phi_get_post, 'usuarios_favores', $phi_get_user);
        delete_user_meta ($phi_get_user, 'favores', $phi_get_post );
    } 
}

add_action ('admin_init', 'phi_admin_preload_get');
```

Comment: its not `get_the_ID()` inside `delete_post_meta()` function. pass just `$post_id` here instead.

Comment: I've made ​​the changes (I've updated the code above) and still not working. Is it possible that the problem is the GET method in Admin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

Change Admin Columns:

```
add_action( "manage_favor_posts_columns", "change_columns" );
function change_columns( $cols ) {
  $cols = array(
    'cb'       => '<input type="checkbox" />',
    'title'     => __( 'Título del favor', 'trans' ),
    'usuarios_registrados'      => __('Usuarios Registrados', 'trans'),
    'date'     => __( 'Fecha publicación', 'trans' ),
  );
  return $cols;
}

add_action( "manage_posts_custom_column", "custom_columns_phi", 10, 2 );
```

Add output metas and delete link in columns:

```
function custom_columns_phi( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case "usuarios_registrados":
            $favor_post_meta_datos = get_post_meta ($post_id, 'usuarios_favores');
            foreach($favor_post_meta_datos as $term_post){      
                $user_phi_name = get_userdata ($term_post);
                ?>
                <li><?echo $user_phi_name->first_name;?> | <a href="<?php print wp_nonce_url(admin_url('edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=favor&value_phi_user='.$term_post.'&value_phi_post='.$post_id));?>">Cancelar</a></li>
                <?
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Add init function in admin screen:

```
function phi_admin_preload_get () {
if ( isset($_GET['value_phi_user'] )) {
        $phi_get_post = $_GET['value_phi_post'];
        $phi_get_user = $_GET['value_phi_user'];
        delete_post_meta ($phi_get_post, 'usuarios_favores', $phi_get_user);
        delete_user_meta ($phi_get_user, 'favores', $phi_get_post );
    } 
}

add_action ('admin_init', 'phi_admin_preload_get');
```